# I want the App keep runing in background in Marshmallow

Tags: android, service, background

I have haweai y6ii mobile phone which has android 6.0.1. I have installed mSpy app which is parental control app. The app is supposed to upload data to the server whenever it is connected to the internet. But due to some issue, the app is not uploading the data automatically. It only uploads data when I manually open the app. Then it keeps sending the data for few hours.But when wifi is turned off, it then does not send data on the next internet connectivity.

I have already added the app in Protected Apps, And have used "Don't Optimize" option under the Battery Optimization. I have also added in the Doze mode but still, it does not upload data when wifi is connected.

Can anyone help and recommend some setting or an app that can allow the app to keep running in the background and upload data to the server when the internet is connected.

Comment: You should contact the app developers and explain your problem to them. They are in a much better position to help you.

Comment: You need a background service to upload data on server

Comment: I contacted them several time but they don't know what exactly is stopping the app.